# android SingleDateTimePicker, how to darken back view

Tags: android, datepicker, android-dialogfragment, dialog-framework

I am using a third party library: `SingleDateTimePicker` https://github.com/florent37/SingleDateAndTimePicker

This is a great way to display a dialog at the bottom of the screen of date and time. This is how I am doing it:

```
new SingleDateAndTimePickerDialog.Builder(getContext())
                .displayMinutes(false)
                .bottomSheet()
                .curved()
                .displayListener(new SingleDateAndTimePickerDialog.DisplayListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onDisplayed(SingleDateAndTimePicker picker) {
                        System.out.println("displayed");
                    }
                })
                .title("Select Time")
                .listener(new SingleDateAndTimePickerDialog.Listener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSelected(Date date) {
                        System.out.println(date.toString());
                        ...
                        ...
                    }
                })
                .display();
```

My only issue here is that when the picker pops up the back screen does not darken to emphasize the popup (like a dialog fragment). Is there a way to darken the background manually?

I tried to put the above library in a layout of its own and inflate it from a `DialogFragment`, however with this approach I am not sure how to call `onDateSelected` to get the date

(at the same time, DialogFragment impose certain layout parameters like, the dialog has to be in the middle of the screen and cannot have a width that `match_parent`. That is why I don't think that putting this in a Dialog Fragment is the way to go)

Note: the non-picker area is clickable. i.e. when clicked the picker area disappears

This is what I have:
[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

use this will take your application style :
https://github.com/Kunzisoft/Android-SwitchDateTimePicker

Comment: This is nowhere close to what the design I am trying to achieve